# How to mount disks based on a ansible facts ansible_devices ids?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, ansible-playbook

i'm trying to mount disks when a ansible device correspond a specific ids name: **google-pgdata**

```
"sdc": {
            "holders": [],
            "host": "",
            "links": {
                "ids": [
                    "google-pgdata",
                    "scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_pgdata"
                ],
                "labels": [],
                "masters": [],
                "uuids": []
            },
            "model": "PersistentDisk",
            "partitions": {},
            "removable": "0",
            "rotational": "1",
            "sas_address": null,
            "sas_device_handle": null,
            "scheduler_mode": "noop",
            "sectors": "209715200",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your disk data by referencing the id's of your ansible facts by:

`{{ ansible_facts['devices']['sdc']['ids'] }}`

You can find more information in the [Ansible playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts).

Also, to mount disks you can follow the reference of the [mount module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html#mount-control-active-and-configured-mount-points) in ansible documentation.